# I want to get Latin-1 codes for specific characters, but I don't know how

Tags: r, parsing, encoding

I'm writing a script using these characters in my coding, like, "ã", "é", etc. But if I close my .R file and reopen it, these characters will be turned to "?" or other random characters. A while ago, I have learned a way to surpass this.

For example, I would rewrite "câmbio" as "c\xe2mbio" and  the problem would be solved, because the code "\xe2" corresponds to "â". The problem is, I don't remember where I found these correspondences.

I thought I have done this by using `parse_character` function. For example: I would type `parse_character("â", locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-8"))` and the code corresponding to the character "â" would appear to me in the output. But it is not working and I can't remember how did I get those Latin-1 codes.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I was expecting that the function `parse_character` was the answer.

Comment: If you wanted to use unicode rather than latin-1 you could do `cat(stringi::stri_escape_unicode("câmbio"))`

Comment: You don't need to write out the codes. You can save and reopen files with specified encodings: https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding-in-the-RStudio-IDE. If you are sharing with others, just make sure they are aware of the encoding you used. For Latin-1, you'll need to check "Show all encodings"